# How to send image same as string from html form in php to server or as a request to an API

Tags: php, html, api, curl, webapi

I was trying to create an simple web application that will analyze image using Microsoft computer vision API. I was unable to get correct output on the app but it is working fine on test endpoints (API is selected from rapidapi.com).

Here is the code:

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image"  required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $curl = curl_init();
            $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['type'], $_FILES['image']['name']);

            $data = array('myimage' => $cfile);
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories%252CTags%252CColor%252CFaces%252CDescription",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
                    "x-rapidapi-host: microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
                    "x-rapidapi-key: b57a0cbabamshcc6da139552c381p1c550ajsn17605aa32e55"
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            if ($err) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        }
    ?>
```

And output is:
`{"code":"NotSupportedVisualFeature","requestId":"0b1ed1a6-afff-43e2-ae50-820d74c9b8fd","message":"Specified feature type is not valid"}`

Comment: It looks like your feature query parameter is not correct. Is it supposed to be encoded like this?

Comment: Any other encoding type will return json with something like "unsupported encoding".

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you encoded a query parameter. Can you try this?

```
    <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <input type="file" name="image"  required>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    <?php
        if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

            $curl = curl_init();
            $cfile = new CURLFile($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $_FILES['image']['type'], $_FILES['image']['name']);

            $data = array('myimage' => $cfile);
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com/analyze?visualfeatures=Categories,Tags,Color,Faces,Description",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 300,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "POST",
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "content-type: multipart/form-data",
                    "x-rapidapi-host: microsoft-azure-microsoft-computer-vision-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
                    "x-rapidapi-key: b57a0cbabamshcc6da139552c381p1c550ajsn17605aa32e55"
                ),
            ));

            $response = curl_exec($curl);
            $err = curl_error($curl);

            curl_close($curl);

            if ($err) {
                echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
            } else {
                echo $response;
            }
        }
    ?>
```